# Using Unicode characters in C# controls

Tags: c#, xaml, unicode

I want to add the Greek letter omega (U+03A9) to a label I've placed on the form. I've already switched the encoding of the form, but how do I set the content of the label such that an omega appears and not UTF char code.

So taking this XAML

```
<Label Height="25">U+03A9</Label>
```

I want the U+03A9 to be converted to an omega

in the code behind I believe I can do something like

```
targetEncoding = Encoding.getEncoding(utfEncoding);
lblOmega.Content = targetEncoding.getBytes("\u03A9");
```

But I'm wondering if I can do this strickly in the XAML

Comment: What do you mean "UTF char code"? Could you show us a tiny sample app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the literal symbol Ω as the control's text. No futher modification necessary.

```
lblOmega.Text = "Ω";
```

Comment: So obvious I didn't even think about that. Ended up just coping and pasting the character directly into the XAML. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear what you mean (in what way have you switched the encoding of the form?) but this works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "-> \u03a9 <-"
                }
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V,
copy "omega" symbol from Character Map to XAML in Visual Studio

```
<TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text=" ꞷ" />
<TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text=" Ω" />
```

[Character Map in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpmEf.png)

how to do it in C # written above. This is a solution for XAML in WPF

Answer (score 0):

using html unicode entity worked for me :

```
                <Label Content="&#937; :" />
```